# biblatex and bibnamedash

Tags: biblatex, punctuation

I'm trying to figure out with biblatex how to have a dash instead of a ibidem when an author is repeated on the same page with `\footcite`. Here is what I have so far:

```
\documentclass[fleqn,10pt]{book}
\usepackage{csquotes}           
\usepackage[style=verbose-trad2,backref=true]{biblatex} 
\bibliography{mem}            
\begin{document}
\section{Text}
some text\footcite[58]{report} some text\footcite[62]{report}
\end{document}
```

with: `mem.bib` as follows:

```
@book{report,
   author =      {Letter, Alphanumeric},
   title =       {On the importance of nice references},
   institution = {typographic University},
   year =        {2011}}
```

I'm not happy with the Ibid. of the second call. How can I replace it by a dash?

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is actually language-specific. Assuming you either use the `babel` package with the `english` option or no language package at all (i.e., with biblatex assuming `english` as a fallback), add the following to your preamble:

```
\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{%
  ibidem = {---},
}
```

EDIT: See sections 3.7 and 4.9.2 of the biblatex documentation for details.